# Adding a browse server image option to my ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to add browse server image option to my ckeditor.
I know I need to add this:

> CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
>               filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: ''
>           });

But what then? What am I to do in order to add this feature to my ckeditor?

What link should I put there?

How I build a directory with all of my images?

What is the difference between "filebrowserImageBrowseUrl" and "extraPlugins: 'imageuploader'"?

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor itself does not provide any server side code that handles image uploads. It just provides JavaScript plugins which let you integrate your own file manager/uploader (if you have any).

If you don't have a file manager, you may try CKFinder, which integrates well with CKEditor: https://cksource.com/ckfinder/download
There is a "CKEditor" example included in the samples folder which shows both applications running together. Make sure to enable CKFinder in `config.php` - due to security reasons it's disabled by default.

Comment: I downloaded CKFinder, but running the sample and clicking on 'Browse server' button, just opens an alert with the text "run();"